# can't control loop index

Tags: python, loops, indexing

```
for flight in range(0,s_count-1):
    for check in range(0,count-1):
       if str(rmr[flight][0])==str(sec[check][0]) or str(rmr[flight][1])==str(sec[check][1]):
            print  'Direct flight exist from '+str(sec[check][0])+' to '+str(sec[check][1])+', price'+str(sec[check][3])+', flight duration '+str(sec[check][2])+'\n'
       else:
            print  'There is no Direct flight from '+str(sec[check][0])+' to '+str(sec[check][1])+'\n'
     break
```

> s_count=6
>
> count=8

count and s_count are numbers representing how many lines there is in two certain files that I took information from.
The information basically are the following

> rmr = [[2, 4], [2, 3], [2, 5], [4, 5], [1, 5]]

`rmr[x][0]` represents 'Origin' and `rmr[x][1]` represents 'Destination'

> sec =
>
> [
>
> [1, 2, 4.0, 100.0],
>
> [2, 3, 1.5, 500.0],
>
> [2, 4, 10.0, 700.0],
>
> [2, 5, 5.75, 1500.0],
>
> [3, 4, 11.4, 200.0],
>
> [4, 5, 10.5, 750.0],
>
> [4, 6, 6.75, 550.0]
>
> ]

`sec[x][0]` represents 'Origin'
`sec[x][1]` represents 'Destination'
`sec[x][2]` represents 'Time'
`sec[x][3]` represents 'Cost'

The whole concept of what I am trying to do about flights' information. According to `rmr[0]` "*Route Matching Request*" a costumer would like go from 'Origin' 2 to 'Destination' 4

and So if we go to `sec[2]` we will see that this flight is available, it would take 10 units of time and cost 700, and so that's what the out should say:

> Direct flight exist from 2 to 4, price 700.0, flight duration 10.0

So I ran this code that I have and this is the output

> There is no Direct flight from 1 to 2
>
> Direct flight exist from 2 to 3, price500.0, flight duration 1.5
>
> Direct flight exist from 2 to 4, price700.0, flight duration 10.0
>
> Direct flight exist from 2 to 5, price1500.0, flight duration 5.75
>
> Direct flight exist from 3 to 4, price200.0, flight duration 11.4
>
> There is no Direct flight from 4 to 5
>
> There is no Direct flight from 4 to 6

While what I expected was

> Direct flight exist from 2 to 4, price700.0, flight duration 10.0
>
> Direct flight exist from 2 to 3, price500.0, flight duration 1.5
>
> Direct flight exist from 2 to 5, price1500.0, flight duration 5.75
>
> Direct flight exist from 4 to 5, price750.0, flight duration 10.5
>
> There is no Direct flight from 1 to 5

Comment: One thing I'd recommend is if this is homework to mention that -> this is a  *very* common request in college CS programs and you clearly need some additional help. I'd recommend going and seeing a mentor or your professor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have a problem with your loop indices, you have a problems with:

- wrong conditional: you want `and` not `or`
- wrong placement of break: you want to stop when you find a direct
- wrong use of else
- no reason for using `str` on everything

This will work:

```
for flight in range(0,s_count-1):
    found = False
    for check in range(0,count-1):
       if rmr[flight][0]==sec[check][0] and rmr[flight][1]==sec[check][1]:
            found = True
            print 'Direct flight exist from {0} to {1}, price {3}, duration {2}'.format(*sec[check])
            break
    if not found:
        print 'There is no Direct flight from {} to {}'.format(*rmr[flight])
```

Comment: One thing I'd recommend: `print 'Direct flight exist from {0} to {1}, price {3}, duration {2}'.format(*sec[check])` & `print 'There is no Direct flight from {} to {}'.format(*rmr[flight])` cleans it up quite nicely via unpacking.

Comment: actually I know that there is no need for the `str()` but I added it later to check if it would matter at all, great help thanks

Answer (score 0):

Most likely the problem is in usage of `range` in:

```
for flight in range(0,s_count-1):
    for check in range(0,count-1):
```

If you want to have numbers from 0 to s_count, excluding s_count, you should just type `range(s_count)`. Same for the second line.

Example:

```
In [1]: list(range(5))
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Comment: umm, if that were the case, the beginning of his outputs would be the same, and the ends would differ...?

Comment: Doesn't really change a thing

Answer (score 0):

try this out:

```
s_count=5
count=7
rmr = [[2, 4], [2, 3], [2, 5], [4, 5], [1, 5]]
sec =[[1, 2, 4.0, 100.0],[2, 3, 1.5, 500.0],[2, 4, 10.0, 700.0],[2, 5, 5.75, 1500.0],[3, 4, 11.4, 200.0],[4, 5, 10.5, 750.0],[4, 6, 6.75, 550.0]]



for flight in range(0,s_count):
    for check in range(0,count):
       if str(rmr[flight][0])==str(sec[check][0]) and str(rmr[flight][1])==str(sec[check][1]):
            print 'Direct flight exist from '+str(sec[check][0])+' to '+str(sec[check][1])+', price'+str(sec[check][3])+', flight duration '+str(sec[check][2])+'\n'         
            break
       if check == count-1 and flight == s_count-1:
            print 'There is no Direct flight from '+str(rmr[flight][0])+' to '+str(rmr[flight][1])+'\n'
```

This basically check to make sure that you have a match between rmr and sec, and then prints the result.  If you're at the end of the loop, you know there is no match, so you can indicate that.

This can obviously be cleaned up and optimized a bit, but it does solve your immediate problem I believe.